# how to remove duplicates from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame of correlation coefficients like the following. In the data frame it has correlation coefficients of `a*b` and `b*a` which are the same. How do I remove this duplicates? Can anyone please help

```
**Var1, Var2, r**
ApoA1.ng.ml.1, Apo.B.ng.ml, 0.9998438
Apo.B.ng.ml, ApoA1.ng.ml.1, 0.9998438
SLM.T0., TBW.T0., 0.9992563
TBW.T0., SLM.T0., 0.9992563
Insulin.mercdiaConc..U.L, Insulin..pg.ml, 0.9313702
Insulin..pg.ml, Insulin.mercdiaConc..U.L, 0.9313702
```

Comment: Provided you always have two matched entries following each other a simple `df[!duplicated(df$r), ]` would work.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, that's begging reliance on R FAQ 7.31, don't you think? I think it is highly unlikely to over-deduplicate with this, but it still seems ... wrong.

Comment: @r2evans Yes you're right, there is the risk of running into floating point issues. Not a robust method at all, yours and Tim's are much preferred! I've come across similar situations multiple times myself and I've always been surprised at how much code is necessary to get rid of these "duplicates"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could try using the `sqldf` package here:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "SELECT MIN(Var1, Var2), MAX(Var2, Var1), MAX(r) AS R
        FROM df
        GROUP BY MIN(Var1, Var2), MAX(Var2, Var1)"

df_out <- sqldf(sql)
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

If the other techniques don't quite work, you can use temporary min/max strings and de-`duplicated` from those:

```
x <- read.csv(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Var1,Var2,r
ApoA1.ng.ml.1,Apo.B.ng.ml,0.9998438
Apo.B.ng.ml,ApoA1.ng.ml.1,0.9998438
SLM.T0.,TBW.T0.,0.9992563
TBW.T0.,SLM.T0.,0.9992563
Insulin.mercdiaConc..U.L,Insulin..pg.ml,0.9313702
Insulin..pg.ml,Insulin.mercdiaConc..U.L,0.9313702")

x[!duplicated(pmin(x$Var1, x$Var2),pmax(x$Var1, x$Var2)),]
#                       Var1           Var2         r
# 1            ApoA1.ng.ml.1    Apo.B.ng.ml 0.9998438
# 3                  SLM.T0.        TBW.T0. 0.9992563
# 5 Insulin.mercdiaConc..U.L Insulin..pg.ml 0.9313702
```

(You can also assign them temporarily to columns in the frame, ala

```
x$m1 <- pmin(x$Var1, x$Var2)
x$m2 <- pmax(x$Var1, x$Var2)
x[!duplicated(x[c("m1","m2")]),]
```

though you then have to remove the temp variables yourself.)